# Vectorise circshift array

Tags: arrays, vectorization, octave

I have a for loop that shifts a signal over a certain amount and appends it to an array.  How can I vectorize the circshift section so I don't need to use the for loop?

```
fs_rate=10
len_of_sig=1; %length of signal in seconds
t=linspace(0,len_of_sig,fs_rate*len_of_sig);

y=.5*sin(2*pi*1*t);
for aa=1:length(y)
  y_new(aa,:)=circshift(y,[1,aa+3]); %shifts signal and appends to array

end
plot(t,y_new)
```

[image: Plot]

PS: I'm using Octave 4.2.2 Ubuntu 18.04 64bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `gallery` to create a circular matrix after using `circshift` for your base shift:

```
base_shift = 4;
fs_rate = 10;
len_of_sig = 1; # length of signal in seconds
t = linspace (0, len_of_sig, fs_rate*len_of_sig);
y = .5 * sin (2*pi*1*t);
y = gallery ("circul", circshift (y, [1 base_shift]));
```

Or if you want to know how it was implemented, take a look at its source code `type gallery`

Comment: Thanks! that looks really nice but in the example I included I tried to increment by `3's` and the gallery option doesn't seem to allow changing the increment number.

Comment: @RickT just use `circshift` for your initial shift. I have edited the answer.